# Un metodo de clase, puede invocar un metodo de instancia?

Tags: objective-c

Intento un metodo que cree un label y lo ponga en pantalla pero este no me lo permite.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No se puede, ambos métodos deben ser del mismo tipo para que uno pueda llamar al otro.

No es buena práctica que un mismo objeto se utilice como instancia y como clase, si lo analizas según el contexto del programa tendrá mas sentido que sea un tipo o el otro.